# test-guide.com Free IQ test question - circles above and below a line

Tags: visual, progressive-matrix

I took an online IQ test(https://www.test-guide.com/iq/free-iq-tests/free-iq-test.html) and encountered a question that I wasn't able to solve:
[image]

I did not find a pattern that produces the third image. I thought that it was a pattern of how the circles moved, but after trying very hard to look for a pattern, I could not find one. Any help in this problem is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate.

Comment: @PrinceDeepthinker Which is the duplicate question?

Comment: I think I have seen this here somewhere before but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's

> 4

because

> Horizontal pattern: Each circle moves one place forward clockwise. So if the circle is above the line, it moves one place to the right and if it's below the line it moves one place to the left. If at the edge, it changes vertical position (above/below the line)